# Is it necessary to install anti-ransomware when you already have anti-virus + anti-exploit?

Tags: security, anti-virus

I already have Avira Antivirus + Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit. (this Anti-Exploit protects from zero-day exploits that target browser, PDF Readers, Office, media players, doesn’t use a signature database—no need for constant updating. This is not an ad, I just don't have the permission to use more than 2 links.)

Plus I'm not a computer noob and I know what not to do.

So, do I need anti-ransomware? If yes, is [CryptoPrevent Free Version](https://www.foolishit.com/cryptoprevent-malware-prevention/) is enough? What about [RansomFree](https://ransomfree.cybereason.com/)? Which combination of all these above is good enough for someone who is careful but can make a mistake?

Comment: I'd generally consider less anti-virus to be better than more. The cure is often worse than the disease. Run a basic antivirus - find one with minimal performance impact and good ratings. Then avoid downloading crap. It's usually not necessary to install many new programs on your computer after Office and games, and those are generally safe. Any new executable from the internet - only install if you are certain it is safe ie you downloaded from the author's page and you trust them. Make backups in case of an actual real problem.

Comment: then the answer is "no, you don't need it"

Comment: @SirAdelaide: OP asks about different tools: anti-virus / -exploit / -ransomware. Are they all synonym of the same tool and do the same? Your comment suggests that. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: My comment is based on answering "do I need anti-ransomware?". All corporate systems I've seen run only antivirus, and daily backup. My personal systems run only Windows Defender and regular backup. I've never had a problem in personal or corporate computing that would have been solved by having more antivirus/exploit programs. But I've certainly seen performance problems from when people had too many of them installed. So based on my experience, it's not needed, and possibly detrimental. Plus ripu says [s]he's not a noob and knows what not do to, thus will avoid ransomware anyway.

Comment: Corporate systems generally also have well configured firewall, restricted user rights and a lot of others in the background which all helps to protect the pc.

Comment: Depends, does Malwarebytes stop ransomeware in the same way this anti-ransomeware software blocks it?  Only true defense against ransom ware is offline backups

Answer (score -2):

I would say it is not necessary. Anti-ransomware has the same problems as antivirus - they need signatures in order to detect a threat and a known threat will be detected by antivirus as well.

What I do recommend is that you enable [File history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17128/windows-8-file-history) (if you use Windows) on top of your regular backups (if you're not doing any yet). I have found File history (or Shadow copies) extremely useful because you don't have to actively monitor it and with proper setup it has the chance to retain a more recent copy of the potentially affected files.

EDIT: To emphasize (even though it's stated above), File history or Shadow copies don't save you from damage. They just help you in automation of some kind of backup, which can be done daily or even every X hours. After you detect the infection you then have a more recent copy then if you make a manual backup.

About disabling File history/Shadow copies. In my experience of solving several ransomware infections these solutions were NOT disabled. And since all ransomware/malware infections don't disable these solutions, you at least stand a greater chance at recovering a more recent state of your files.

Comment: I've downvoted you simply because this reads like File History (shadow copies) will protect you from ransomware/malware. If you can re-word it to show this isn't always the case, and that even shadow copies are not a back up then I'd upvote instead.

Comment: One of the first thing that gets disabled by 9/10 ransomeare infections is Shadow Copies and File History